# AVAudioPlayer is not restarting the bg music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, avaudioplayer

I'm on latest Xcode version. I'm using following code to restart my background music. But these codes are not restarting the background music.

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"game" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
[player stop];
player.currentTime = 0;
[player play];
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm not getting errors. But every time when I click on start button, the  music is keep playing over and over at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To use AVAudioPlayer, you need a strong reference to it. Try to set the player as a property of your controller, then use `[self.player play]`

Answer (score 0):

Declare AVAudioPlayer into .h file.